# MySQL query select statement not finding committed entries

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, discord.py

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO License VALUES('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '0', '{}')"
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

The statement above inserts information into my Database and commits it correctly, and I've verified it is in the Database.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM License WHERE License_Key = '{}' AND Used = 0"
keyInfo = cur.fetchone()
cur.close()
```

The statement above attempts to find the information depended on what it can find within the Database matching the where clause.

When I attempt to execute the SELECT query through a Discord Bot's command it will not find the information until the Discord Bot is manually restarted.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: That query doesn't do anything. It _almost_ seems to use string formatting, which leaves you open to SQL injection, but it doesn't even do that. What is `{}` supposed to refer to?

Comment: I use .format() to insert the License_Key in this case but removed it for the sake of this post, and yes I'm aware of the security issues and just am using this for the time being during testing.

Comment: "The time being". It is _never_ easier to do this the incorrect way. People get tied up in all sorts of knots trying what they think is easiest. Use parameterized queries because soon you're going to have massive strings trying to escape characters and all sorts. As it stands, though, I'm not sure this can be answered from what you've given.

Comment: What I'm attempting to accomplish is when the information is inserted into the Database I want to select said information with a discord command that either finds it and succeeds or fails and does nothing past that. When I attempt to select the information it's as if it doesn't exist in the Database but am 100% sure it's present in the Database because I verified such through MySQL workbench. Thanks for the tips thus far I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, but I wasn't asking for another statement of the problem. The code you've given doesn't actually do anything. It's unclear to me what we are supposed to be answering.

Comment: Use parametrized strings: lookup how here: http://bobby-tables.com/python

Comment: Ah gotcha, so basically with the insert statement I'm taking information given from a Stripe webhook and inserting it into the Database and generating a unique License Key as well and adding it into the Database. After that the user should receive an email and then can join the determined Discord and gain access using their license key, but when this activation command is run aka the select statement it will return "Activation Failed" due to it not being found within the Database. Like I mentioned previously only after the Discord Bot is restarted will it find that information and succeed.